# Matplotlib: how to automatically draw an axes title at the left-most position?

Tags: matplotlib

I'm drawing my axes title with the method `ax.set_title("Horizontal Bars", ha="left", x=0, fontsize=16)` and it draw as below:

[image: Horizontal bar chart with misplaced title]

How do I draw it in the left-most position, as the "title here" in red above? I know I can use a negative value for x, but I'd like to find this value automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically generate the bounds you would do:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)


plt.rcdefaults()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Example data
people = ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Slim', 'Jim')
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
performance = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
error = np.random.rand(len(people))

ax.barh(y_pos, performance, xerr=error, align='center')
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(people)
ax.invert_yaxis()  # labels read top-to-bottom
ax.set_xlabel('Performance')

# Get min x and max y
# get the inverse of the transformation from data coordinates to pixels
transf = ax.transData.inverted()
bb = plt.figure().get_window_extent(renderer = plt.figure().canvas.get_renderer())
bb_datacoords = bb.transformed(transf)
points = bb_datacoords.get_points()
x_lim = points[0][0]
y_lim = points[1][1]

ax.text(x=x_lim, y=y_lim, s="Horizontal Bars", weight="bold", fontsize=16) # <- Use text instead of title
```

which gives you an output of:

[image: dynamically generated title]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why are you using `-3` in `ax.text(-3, -1, "Horizontal Bars")` ? How do you know that -3 is the left-most x position?

Comment: When you use `-3` in this case it is relative to the x-axis or the `Performance` axis below. So the origin is the bottom left of the above plot.

Comment: I added another example to better demonstrate this

Comment: I understand, but I can do the same with settitle: `ax.set_title('Titlte', x=-3,ha='left')`. This value will change for each plot. I'd like a way to automatically position it. I'll change my question to make it clearer.

Comment: See the new edit and you should have a plot that dynamically puts the title in the top left!